# Comparing Haskell and Scala Bind/Flatmap Examples

Tags: scala, haskell

The following `bind(>>=)` code, in Haskell, does not compile:

```hs
ghci> [[1]] >>= Just
<interactive>:38:11:
    Couldn't match type ‘Maybe’ with ‘[]’
    Expected type: [t] -> [[t]]
      Actual type: [t] -> Maybe [t]
    In the second argument of ‘(>>=)’, namely ‘Just’
    In the expression: [[1]] >>= Just
```

But, in Scala, it does actually compile and run:

```scala
scala> List( List(1) ).flatMap(x => Some(x) )
res1: List[List[Int]] = List(List(1))
```

Haskell's `>>=` signature is:

`>>= :: Monad m => m a -> (a -> m b) -> m b`

So, in `[[1]] >>= f`, `f`'s type should be: `a -> [b]`.

Why does the Scala code compile?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

As @chi explained Scala's `flatMap` is more general than the Haskell's `>>=`. The full signature from the Scala docs is:

```
final def flatMap[B, That](f: (A) ⇒ GenTraversableOnce[B])(implicit bf: CanBuildFrom[List[A], B, That]): That
```

This implicit isn't relevant for this specific problem, so we could as well use the simpler definition:

```
final def flatMap[B](f: (A) ⇒ GenTraversableOnce[B]): List[B]
```

There is only one Problem, `Option` is no subclass of `GenTraversableOnce`, here an implicit conversion comes in. Scala defines an implicit conversion from `Option` to `Iterable` which is a subclass of `Traversable` which is a subclass of `GenTraversableOnce`.

```
implicit def option2Iterable[A](xo: Option[A]): Iterable[A]
```

The implicit is defined in the companion object of `Option`.

A simpler way to see the implicit at work is to assign a `Option` to an `Iterable` `val`:

```
scala> val i:Iterable[Int] = Some(1)
i: Iterable[Int] = List(1)
```

Scala uses some defaulting rules, to select `List` as the implementation of `Iterable`.

The fact that you can combine different subtypes of `TraversableOnce` with monad operations comes from the `implicit class` `MonadOps`:

```
  implicit class MonadOps[+A](trav: TraversableOnce[A]) {
    def map[B](f: A => B): TraversableOnce[B] = trav.toIterator map f
    def flatMap[B](f: A => GenTraversableOnce[B]): TraversableOnce[B] = trav.toIterator flatMap f
    def withFilter(p: A => Boolean) = trav.toIterator filter p
    def filter(p: A => Boolean): TraversableOnce[A] = withFilter(p)
  }
```

This enhances every `TraversableOnce` with the methods above. The subtypes are free to define more efficient versions on there own, these will shadow the implicit definitions. This is the case for `List`.

Comment: Is that just `List`s `flatMap` or does this work for every type in Scala?

Comment: The `GenTraversableOnce` is used for all "list like" collections in Scala. It's possible to use e.g. a `Vector` in combination with a `List`. `Vector(1).flatMap(x=>List(x)) == Vector(1)` or `List(1).flatMap(x=>Vector(x)) == List(1)`

Comment: Nah, I wondered whether the use of `GenTraversableOnce` in the `flatMap` signature is a generalisation that is specific to lists, or is working in all monads (types with a `flatMap` method?)?

Comment: It's only defined this way for `List`, `Vector` and probably some other similar types. `Option` on the other hand has a simple `flatMap` as you would expect: `final def flatMap[B](f: (A) ⇒ Option[B]): Option[B]`

Comment: @Bergi I've looked into it and it seems that every subclass of `TraversableOnce` shows this behavior, I've added the details to my answer.

Answer (score 12):

Quoting from the Scala reference for [`List`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.11.6/#scala.collection.immutable.List)

```
final def flatMap[B](f: (A) ⇒ GenTraversableOnce[B]): List[B]
```

So, `flatMap` is more general than Haskell's `(>>=)`, since it only requires the mapped function `f` to generate a traversable type, not necessarily a `List`.

Comment: where do i see in the signature `(a -> m b)` that the function should generate a traversable type, i only see that the function should produce `m b` but m is general isn't it where does it say a list? isn't a list denoted in haskell by `[]` i don't see any `[]` in the haskell bind definition...

Comment: @Jas Above I'm only saying that Scala's bind _for lists_ (shown above) is more general than Haskell's bind _for lists_. I am not comparing the general bind (Scala has no "general" bind, only classes which happen to have a flatMap, IIRC). In Haskell, we have a list-bind `[a] -> (a -> [b]) -> [b]` when in Scala it is more similar to `[a] -> (a -> t b) -> [b]` for a suitable `t`.

Answer (score 0):

**A Perspective:**

Given that Haskell's `>>=` signature is:

```
( >>= ) :: (Monad m) => m a -> (a -> m b) -> m b
```

You need to make sure that you properly recognize the types of `a` and `b`.

Given the initial part of the expression ...

```
[ [1] ] >>= ...
```

This suggests that `m` corresponds to `[]`, which then implies that the type `a` refers to `[Int]`.

Given this recognition, `Just` doesn't have the appropriate structure.  In order to be consistent with what you have, you'd need something like:

```
f :: [Int] -> [Maybe [Int]] = \x -> [Just x]
```

If you use that, then you should get:

```
ghci> [[1]] >>= f
[Just [1]]
```

In Scala, if you do something like:

```
    trait Monad[M[_] : Applicative]:
      extension [A](a: A)
        def rtrn() : M[A] // Scala version of Haskell's return
      extension [A](x: M[A])
        def >>=[B](h: A => M[B]): M[B]
        def >:>[B](y: M[B]): M[B] = x >>= ( (_ : A) => y )
```

In order to have the code be simple and be consistent with Haskell's general picture, it is assumed that `Functor` and `Applicative` have also been defined.  The notation used above is not idiomatic Scala, but rather used to draw a greater parallel with Haskell's syntax.  Notice that `rtrn` is used instead of `return` and `>:>` instead of `>>`.

An instance of `Monad` for `List` could look like:

```
    given Monad[List] with
      extension [A](x: A)
        def rtrn():List[A] = List( x )
      extension [A](xs: List[A])
        def >>=[B](h: A => List[B]): List[B] = 
          xs.fmap(h)
            .foldLeft(List() : List[B])( (_ ++ _) : (List[B], List[B]) => List[B])
```

Since it's assumed that `Functor` and `Applicative` have been written, `fmap` would be defined in the `Functor` trait.

Using this, you can replicate the Haskell result in Scala.

```
scala> List(List(1)) >>= ( (u : List[Int]) => List ( Some ( u ) ) ) 
val res0: List[Some[List[Int]]] = List(Some(List(1)))
```

As others have indicated, Scala's `flatMap` is essentially just a more general form of `>>=`.  Thus, when applied like the above, you get the same result!

```
scala> List(List(1)).flatMap( (u : List[Int]) => List ( Some ( u ) ) )
val res4: List[Some[List[Int]]] = List(Some(List(1)))
```

Abstracting things just a little bit, the effective type-signature for flatMap is effectively (using Haskell syntax):

```
flatMap :: (Monad m, ??? t) => m a -> (a -> t b) -> m b
```

The `???` above is something that includes the `Monad` kind, but is even weaker (thereby making it to be more general).