# Behavior of flatMap when applied to List[Option[T]]

Tags: scala, functional-programming

Let's take a look at this code:

```
scala> val a = List(Some(4), None)
a: List[Option[Int]] = List(Some(4), None)
scala> a.flatMap( e=> e)
List[Int] = List(4)
```

Why would applying `flatMap` with the function `{ e => e }` on a `List[Option[T]]` returns a `List[T]` with the `None` elements removed?

Specifically, what is the **conceptual reasoning** behind it -- is it based on some existing theory in functional programming? Is this behavior common in other functional languages?

This, while indeed useful, does feel a bit magical and arbitrary at the same time.

EDIT:

*Thank you for your feedbacks and answer.
I have rewritten my question to put more emphasis on the conceptual nature of the question. Rather than the Scala specific implementation details, I'm more interested in knowing the formal concepts behind it.*

Comment: Depends on what your mapper function does? Please show an example. See also [this answer maybe](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29188246/1048572)

Comment: Are you sure you don't mean `flatten`?

Comment: Aha,  that flatMap is basically a combination of map and flatten makes it reasonably clear for me. However I'm still waiting for a more comprehensive answer.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Let's first look at the Scaladoc for Option's companion object.  There we see an implicit conversion:

```
implicit def option2Iterable[A](xo: Option[A]): Iterable[A]
```

This means that any option can be *implicitly* converted to an Iterable, resulting in a collection with zero or one elements.  If you have an `Option[A]` where you need an `Iterable[A]`, the compiler will add the conversion for you.

In your example:

```
val a = List(Some(4), None)
a.flatMap(e => e)
```

We are calling `List.flatMap`, which takes a function `A => GenTraversableOnce[B]`.  In this case, `A` is `Option[Int]` and `B` will be inferred as `Int`, because through the magic of implicit conversion, `e` when returned in that function will be converted from an `Option[Int]` to an `Iterable[Int]` (which is a subtype of `GenTraversableOnce`).

At this point, we've essentially done the following:

```
List(List(1), Nil).flatMap(e => e)
```

Or, to make our implicit explicit:

```
List(Option(1), None).flatMap(e => e.toList)
```

`flatMap` then works on Option as it does for any linear collection in Scala: take a function of `A => List[B]` (again, simplifying) and produce a flattened collection of `List[B]`, un-nesting the nested collections in the process.

Answer (score 8):

I assume you mean the support for mapping and filtering at the same time with `flatMap`:

```
scala> List(1, 2).flatMap {
     |   case i if i % 2 == 0 => Some(i)
     |   case i => None
     | }
res0: List[Int] = List(2)
```

This works because `Option`'s [companion object](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.Option$) includes an implicit conversion from `Option[A]` to `Iterable[A]`, which is a `GenTraversableOnce[A]`, which is what `flatMap` expects as the return type for its argument function.

It's a convenient idiom, but it doesn't really exist in other functional languages (at least the ones I'm familiar with), since it relies on Scala's weird mix of subtyping, implicit conversions, etc. Haskell for example provides similar functionality through [`mapMaybe` for lists](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.7.0.2/docs/Data-Maybe.html#v:mapMaybe), though.

Comment: Just as a note for people considering using this idiom, I feel like `collect` is underutilized in place of this `flatMap`.  In this example, we could have a much cleaner:  `List(1,2).collect { case i if i % 2 == 0 => i }`

Comment: I was under the impression that Haskell's `bind` is of similar functionality. Can you clarify this if you're familiar with Haskell?

Comment: @lolski Haskell doesn't have subtyping (or implicit conversions), so there's no relationship at all between lists and `Maybe`. When you use Haskell's bind (`>>=`) on a list, you need a function that returns a list, and when you use it on a `Maybe`, you need a function that returns `Maybe`—you can't mix and match (except via different functions like `mapMaybe` that are designed specifically for mixing and matching).

Answer (score 0):

A short answer to your question is: the `flatMap` method of the `List` type is defined to work with a more general function type, not just a function that only produces a `List[B]` result type.

The general result type is `IterableOnce[B]`, as shown in the `faltMap` method signature:  `final def flatMap[B](f: (A) => IterableOnce[B]): List[B]`. The [`flatMap` implementation](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/v2.13.1/src/library/scala/collection/immutable/List.scala#L260) is rather simple in that it applies the `f` function to each element and iterates over the result in a nested `while` loop. All results from the nested loop are added to a result of type `List[B]`.

Therefore the `flatMap` works with any function that produces an `IterableOnce[B]` result from each list element. The [`IterableOnce`](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/collection/IterableOnce.html) is a trait that defines a minimal interface that is inherited by all iterable classes, including all collection types (`Set`, `Map` and etc.) and the `Option` class.

The [`Option` class implementation](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/v2.13.1/src/library/scala/Option.scala#L560) returns `collection.Iterator.empty` for `None` and `collection.Iterator.single(x)` for `Some(x)`. Therefore the `flatMap` method skips `None` element.

The question uses the `identity` function. It is better to use `flatten` method when the purpose is to flat `iterable` elements.

```scala
scala> val a = List(Some(4), None)
a: List[Option[Int]] = List(Some(4), None)

scala> a.flatten
res0: List[Int] = List(4)
```