# Why do we need flatMap (in general)?

Tags: scala, functional-programming, flatmap

I have been looking into FP languages (off and on) for some time and have played with Scala, Haskell, F#, and some others.  I like what I see and understand some of the fundamental concepts of FP (with absolutely *no* background in Category Theory - so don't talk Math, please).

So, given a type `M[A]` we have `map` which takes a function `A=>B` and returns a `M[B]`.  But we also have `flatMap` which takes a function `A=>M[B]` and returns a `M[B]`.  We also have `flatten` which takes a `M[M[A]]` and returns a `M[A]`.

In addition, many of the sources I have read describe `flatMap` as `map` followed by `flatten`.

So, given that `flatMap` seems to be equivalent to `flatten compose map`, what is its purpose?  Please don't say it is to support 'for comprehensions' as this question really isn't Scala-specific.  And I am less concerned with the syntactic sugar than I am in the concept behind it.  The same question arises with Haskell's bind operator (`>>=`).  I believe they both are related to some Category Theory concept but I don't speak that language.

I have watched Brian Beckman's great video [Don't Fear the Monad](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZhuHCtR3xq8&feature=kp) more than once and I think I see that `flatMap` is the monadic composition operator but I have never really seen it used the way he describes this operator.  Does it perform this function?  If so, how do I map that concept to `flatMap`?

BTW, I had a long writeup on this question with lots of listings showing experiments I ran trying to get to the bottom of the meaning of `flatMap` and then ran into [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29214127/behavior-of-flatmap-when-applied-to-listoptiont) which answered some of my questions.  Sometimes I hate Scala implicits. They can really muddy the waters. :)

Comment: Well isn't `xss.flatten` just shorthand for `xss.flatMap(identity)`, so `flatten` derives from `flatMap`, rather than the other way round? Though for explaining things, I suppose `flatten` is a bit easier to get your head around.

Comment: @LuigiPlinge, yeah I have seen that explained as well.  I know many of the manipulations available with `flatMap` and how it can be used.  I just don't think I really *understand* it.  There seems to be a concept that I just can't quite grasp somewhere.

Comment: I've come back to this question after getting a notice that it is now a 'Notable' question.  The answers I got here plus the info in Brian Beckman's video mentioned above started me off in the direction of understanding monads.  I am now comfortable in most uses of FP and regularly use it in my daily work - even in "non-FP" languages (like Java and C++).  I am very grateful to all those who answered my question.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

FlatMap, known as "bind" in some other languages, is as you said yourself for function composition.

Imagine for a moment that you have some functions like these:

```
def foo(x: Int): Option[Int] = Some(x + 2)
def bar(x: Int): Option[Int] = Some(x * 3)
```

The functions work great, calling `foo(3)` returns `Some(5)`, and calling `bar(3)` returns `Some(9)`, and we're all happy.

But now you've run into the situation that requires you to do the operation more than once.

```
foo(3).map(x => foo(x)) // or just foo(3).map(foo) for short
```

Job done, right?

Except not really. The output of the expression above is `Some(Some(7))`, not `Some(7)`, and if you now want to chain another map on the end you can't because `foo` and `bar` take an `Int`, and not an `Option[Int]`.

Enter `flatMap`

```
foo(3).flatMap(foo)
```

Will return `Some(7)`, and

```
foo(3).flatMap(foo).flatMap(bar)
```

Returns `Some(15)`.

This is great! Using `flatMap` lets you chain functions of the shape `A => M[B]` to oblivion (in the previous example `A` and `B` are `Int`, and `M` is `Option`).

More technically speaking; `flatMap` and `bind` have the signature `M[A] => (A => M[B]) => M[B]`, meaning they take a "wrapped" value, such as `Some(3)`, `Right('foo)`, or `List(1,2,3)` and shove it through a function that would normally take an unwrapped value, such as the aforementioned `foo` and `bar`. It does this by first "unwrapping" the value, and then passing it through the function.

I've seen the box analogy being used for this, so observe my expertly drawn MSPaint illustration:
[image]

This unwrapping and re-wrapping behavior means that if I were to introduce a third function that doesn't return an `Option[Int]` and tried to `flatMap` *it* to the sequence, it wouldn't work because `flatMap` expects you to return a monad (in this case an `Option`)

```
def baz(x: Int): String = x + " is a number"

foo(3).flatMap(foo).flatMap(bar).flatMap(baz) // <<< ERROR
```

To get around this, if your function doesn't return a monad, you'd just have to use the regular `map` function

```
foo(3).flatMap(foo).flatMap(bar).map(baz)
```

Which would then return `Some("15 is a number")`

Comment: This answer is clear and concise, answers precisely what the question asks AND has awesome graphics. I wish I could upvote twice

Comment: This is probably the best description of the concept behind flatMap/bind I have seen.  Thanks.

Comment: Nice answer, I think though that the `flatMap:` part of the diagram should show the flatMap mapping then flattering rather than flattering then mapping.

Comment: I don't think your update is relevant, since `foldLeft` only works for lists

Answer (score 2):

It's the same reason you provide more than one way to do anything: it's a common enough operation that you may want to wrap it.

You could ask the opposite question: why have `map` and `flatten` when you already have `flatMap` and a way to store a single element inside your collection?  That is,

```
x map f
x filter p
```

can be replaced by

```
x flatMap ( xi => x.take(0) :+ f(xi) )
x flatMap ( xi => if (p(xi)) x.take(0) :+ xi else x.take(0) )
```

so why bother with `map` and `filter`?

In fact, there are various minimal sets of operations you need to reconstruct many of the others (`flatMap` is a good choice because of its flexibility).

Pragmatically, it's better to have the tool you need.  Same reason why there are non-adjustable wrenches.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest reason is to compose an output set where each entry in the input set may produce more than one (or zero!) outputs.

For example, consider a program which outputs addresses for people to generate mailers. Most people have one address. Some have two or more. Some people, unfortunately, have none. Flatmap is a generalized algorithm to take a list of these people and return all of the addresses, regardless of how many come from each person.

The zero output case is particularly useful for monads, which often (always?) return exactly zero or one results (think Maybe- returns zero results if the computation fails, or one if it succeeds). In that case you want to perform an operation on "all of the results", which it just so happens may be one or many.

Comment: This is closer to what I was looking for, I think.  I understand the 0/1 element case that `flatMap` seems to cover pretty well.  In looking at some of the material I have found online it seems to indicate that it should fulfill kind of the same role as `compose`, though.  But that is just an impression I am trying to confirm or dispel.

Comment: Compose is completely different. Compose executes the first (function) argument and passes the results to the second function. What might have you confused is that flatMap is the result of composing the map and flatten functions- first map the results from the input, then flatten those results into a single sequence.

Comment: However, Brian Beckman explains Haskell's bind operator `>>=` as a monadic composition operator.  And, otherwise it seems to be the same as `flatMap`.  Was he wrong?

Comment: No- but flatMap is the superset of functionality in that case. Monadic composition is only for 0 or 1 results, whereas flatMap is for 0 or more.

Answer (score 1):

The "flatMap", or "bind", method, provides an invaluable way to chain together methods that provide their output wrapped in a Monadic construct (like `List`, `Option`, or `Future`). For example, suppose you have two methods that produce a `Future` of a result (eg. they make long-running calls to databases or web service calls or the like, and should be used asynchronously):

```
def fn1(input1: A): Future[B]  // (for some types A and B)

def fn2(input2: B): Future[C]  // (for some types B and C)
```

How to combine these? With `flatMap`, we can do this as simply as:

```
def fn3(input3: A): Future[C] = fn1(a).flatMap(b => fn2(b))
```

In this sense, we have "composed" a function `fn3` out of `fn1` and `fn2` using `flatMap`, which has the same general structure (and so can be composed in turn with further similar functions).

The `map` method would give us a not-so-convenient - and not readily chainable - `Future[Future[C]]`. Certainly we can then use `flatten` to reduce this, but the `flatMap` method does it in one call, and can be chained as far as we wish.

This is so useful a way of working, in fact, that Scala provides the for-comprehension as essentially a short-cut for this (Haskell, too, provides a short-hand way of writing a chain of bind operations - I'm not a Haskell expert, though, and don't recall the details) - hence the talk you will have come across about for-comprehensions being "de-sugared" into a chain of `flatMap` calls (along with possible `filter` calls and a final `map` call for the `yield`).

Comment: Thanks.  So `flatMap` really is a way to chain monad-producing functions the same way `map` can be used to chain 'normal' functions.   That is, functions that are defined as `A -> B`.

Comment: @melston Yes, that is a reasonable way to think of it.

Answer (score 0):

Well, one could argue, you don't need `.flatten` either. Why not just do something like

```
@tailrec
def flatten[T](in: Seq[Seq[T], out: Seq[T] = Nil): Seq[T] = in match {
   case Nil => out
   case head ::tail => flatten(tail, out ++ head)
}
```

Same can be said about map:

```
@tailrec
def map[A,B](in: Seq[A], out: Seq[B] = Nil)(f: A => B): Seq[B] = in match {
   case Nil => out
   case head :: tail => map(tail, out :+ f(head))(f)
  }
```

So, why are `.flatten` and `.map` provided by the library? Same reason `.flatMap` is: convenience.

There is also `.collect`, which is really just

```
list.filter(f.isDefinedAt _).map(f)
```

`.reduce` is actually nothing more then `list.foldLeft(list.head)(f)`,
`.headOption` is

```
list match {
    case Nil => None
    case head :: _ => Some(head)
}
```

Etc ...

Comment: I was hoping for more than TMTOWTDI :)  I have seen map defined in terms of `flatMap` and vice versa (for `List`s) so I kind of get that.  I was looking for more of a push in some conceptual direction.  Though I usually forget about `collect`.  Thanks for the reminder.